# grails URL transformation with url-mappings

Tags: grails

I want to use Url-Mappings to transform the url.

```
"/blog/$system?"(controller:"blog", action:"home")
```

What I want to achieve is

```
"/blog/bob"
```

should become

```
 "/blog/home?system=bob"
```

It doesn't seem to work as I excpected. What is my misunderstanding? Can I get this done? How?

Answer (score 0):

remove the mapping, then Grails will use the default one:

```
"/$controller/$action"()
```

which in your case would be

```
 /blog/home?system=bob
```